# In F#, how to list the PrintQueues from the PrintQueueCollection?

Tags: printing, f#

(Newbie question).

I am attempting to list out the PrintQueues from the Microsoft PrintQueColletion in F#. Something like this:

```
let GetPrinters :List<PrintQueue> = 
        let localPrintServer = new PrintServer()
        let printQueues = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues [|EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local; EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections|]
        let printerList = printQueues |> ????
        printerList
```

But I can't get how to turn the **PrintQueueCollection** into a list of **PrintQueue**.

Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

TIA

Hint: in C#, this is:

```
public static List<PrintQueue> GetPrinters()
        {
            PrintServer localPrintServer = new PrintServer();
            PrintQueueCollection printQueues = localPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] {
                    EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local,
                    EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });

            var printerList = (from printer in printQueues
                               select printer)
                                .ToList();

            return printerList;
        }
```

Comment: Also worth noting that `List<'T>` in F# is different than in C#. If you need a .NET `List<'T>`, then you can construct a `ResizeArray` with `prinQueues` and that would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE: See improved answer below this one.**

---

This should do it:

```
let printerList =
    printQueues
        |> Seq.cast<PrintQueue>
        |> Seq.toList
```

The trick here is that if you want `printQueues` to behave like an `IEnumerable<PrintQueue>`, you have to explicitly wrap it. This is what `Seq.cast` does.

(Side note: This is just one reason why having weakly-typed `FooCollection` classes instead of using built-in strongly-typed collections is a bad idea in general. Such is the legacy of old C# code.)

Answer (score 2):

My first answer isn't technically correct, so I want to fix it here to make sure you see the update. It turns out that you don't need an explicit cast in this case, so the following simpler code will also work:

```
let printerList =
    printQueues
        |> Seq.toList
```

The rest of my explanation in the previous answer is correct for handling weakly-typed collections, but `PrintQueueCollection` is actually a strongly-typed `IEnumerable<PrintQueue>`, so it works just fine with the `Seq` module as it is. Sorry about that.

Comment: The normal thing to do would be to edit the first answer.

Comment: Yes, but OP already accepted the first answer and I wanted to make sure OP saw the correction.

Comment: @brianberns  Both answers are great! Your explanation as to why the second answer works is every bit as important to me as the answer itself. For what it's worth, understanding the first answer is more "generic" and closer to what I was thinking in my simpleton mind :)   Thanks for the learning moment.

Comment: @brianberns as SO aims to not only be a one off answering service, editing the first answer to at least say something along the lines “Update: wrong / see better way...” would be nice. Better yet: edit and write a comment “@OP: ...”